# .NET CORE - can ApplicationBuilder Map() path be case sensitive

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I am trying to make Map('/fr') case sensitive, is it possible?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Map middleware uses [`StartsWithSegments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.pathstring.startswithsegments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_PathString_StartsWithSegments_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_PathString_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_PathString__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_PathString__) with the default `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`. As such, the Map middleware will always make a case-insensitive check for path prefixes.

However, the Map middleware in itself isn’t that complicated so you could always roll your own logic. This makes especially sense since you appear to build your own middleware anyway. So you can just move the path check inside your middleware:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/fr", StringComparison.Ordinal, out var remaining)
    {
        // path starts with `/fr` (case-sensitive)
        // remaining path (after the `/fr`) is in `remaining`

        await next();
    }
});
```

Comment: how about using MapWhen? isn't it the same as your solution?

Comment: Yes, you could also use `MapWhen` but you will still need to make the check yourself.